# how to get the system backpress event in the child widget of the Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

I am unable to get back press event in onWillPop method in WillPopScope widget
as mentioned below i am using bottom navigation and for that i am using Navigator for all screen and i need back press event in one of that screens

here is my navigator:-

```
Navigator(
      key: workHistoryNavigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            switch (settings.name) {
              case '/':
                return WorkHistoryScreen();
              case Routes.workHistoryDetailScreen:
                return WorkHistoryDetailScreen();
            }
            return Container();
          },
        );
      },
    );
```

below is my child screen used in navigator

```
  class WorkHistoryDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const WorkHistoryDetailScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<WorkHistoryDetailScreen> createState() => _WorkHistoryDetailScreenState();
    }
    
    class _WorkHistoryDetailScreenState extends State<WorkHistoryDetailScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return WillPopScope(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: [],
            ),
          ),
          onWillPop: () async {
            //i am not getting any events here when i press back 
            return false;
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

I need back press event in WorkHistoryDetailScreen
and this screen is part of navigator and that navigator i have used in bottom navigation

I have tried a lot but not find out any results regarding this

Comment: are you able to get back from this screen to previous using this code

Answer (score 0):

> You can add appbar in scaffold widget :

```
WillPopScope(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            // ... your content ...
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
        return true; // Return true to allow the pop
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: i need system back button press event i have implemented this but with that i have to manage some of my code on systen back button also